# WordPress Taxonomy Page Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am trying to create different post types for each section of my website, but I am stuck.

This is what I have so far:

```
function create_post_type() {
   register_post_type( 'information',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Information' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Information' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'information'),
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
      'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-admin-post',
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );
function build_taxonomies() {
     register_taxonomy(
      'information',
      'information',
      array(
          'hierarchical' => true,
          'label' => 'Type',
          'query_var' => 'information',
          'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'type' )
      )
  );
}
```

It shows in the left sidebar on the panel Information / Add new / Type

In my website I see the post and a sidebar with all 'Types' I have registered.

I need to see, for example:

mywebsite.com/information/daily -> list all posts in information marked with daily taxonomy.

That is:
mywebsite.com/customposttype/taxonomy

Actually I have a taxonomy-information.php with a loop, but it sends me to the homepage (tried taxonomy-type.php, taxonomy-information-type.php, no one works).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First try to re-save your permalink structure (and make sure wordpress has permissions to change .htaccess file in your root).

Second, I don't think its a very good idea to name both the post type and the taxonomy the same, and then renaming it's slug.. Is there any good reason to do so?

Comment: I tried it, no success. Ended up using normal posts with categories and subcategories ... about the taxonomy and post type, I changed both to 'information' here in Stack Overflow because in my code it was using words in another language. Thanks for your reply.